# zero at the beginning of data mysql

Tags: php, mysqli

I stored data on my data base.and now I want to fetch it.but there are zeros at the beginning of data.and when I fetch the data the zeros are deleted.

for example I stored "0064" and when I fetch it ,display "64".

```
       $sql1="select * from book where id='$code'";
       $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql1);
       if(!mysqli_query($con,$sql1))
       {
        die('error' .mysqli_error($con));
       }
       $row = mysqli_fetch_array( $result ,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

and when I want to fetch in textbox I use this code:

```
 <input type="text" size="15"  value="<? echo $row['id'] ?>">
```

how can I keep those zeros?
thanks

Comment: You stored them in an integer column?Why not store them in a varchar column and later cast them to an integer if necessary?

Comment: The other approach is to use unsigned zerofill with length of 4 for the id column.

Comment: Hey Whats wrong with my ans ? sometime it is use for API data where u cant set id as int

Comment: @SubhraSekharMukhopadhyay when you convert back you will still get 64.The zeroes are lost.How will you append them?By assumption?What if another entry is 000000640?How will you append the chars?Btw,I wasn't the one who downvoted you.

Comment: Thank For your comment Mr. @AlvinArulselvan but i really try this some days ago and work properly

Comment: Mr.  AlvinArulselvan data type of this field is "varchar" but still I have that problem!!

Comment: When you echo the $row['id'] outside the html,what does it show?0064 or 64?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to change your schema structure. Instead of `INT`, you need to define your field as `CHAR` or `VARCHAR`, so that you can save the data with zero as prefix. The integer field is not allowed to do this (as in an Excel sheet).

Comment: Use INT's when you can, especially if its just some minor formating.

Answer (score 2):

Add these zeros after getting id from database

```
str_pad($input, 4, $row['id'], STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

or you can redefine your table structure with

```
id INT(4) ZEROFILL
```

with the same ecffect.

The main point is to **store** a number but **display** whatever fancy format you wish.

Comment: I use wamp server.how can I change the data type of one field of my table to int(4)zerofill?

Answer (score -2):

Before you fetch data, convert the ID field into a `varchar`. The query will then be the following one.

```
 $sql1 = "select * from book where id LIKE '$code'";
 $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql1);
 if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql1)) {
   die('error' .mysqli_error($con));
 }
 $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

Comment: again when you will echo $row['id'] it will give the same

Comment: Try Yourself @rajeev , i dont think so

Comment: you had just changed the condition of the query not the way it produces result.

Comment: please see the top of the code where i said "before you fetch data , the convert id field int to varchar" @RajeevRanjan